# Is there a way to get the jQuery function to instantly work onload the first time?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, menu

I created a website for a client which seems to glitch when it loads for the first time. The menu button does not work unless you refresh the page. Is there a way to get the jQuery function to continuously work?

I looked through it but cannot find the problem. please see the below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Function to change the nav-bar on scroll
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) ? (
      $('.fixed-nav-bar').addClass('scrolled'),
      $('.the-bass').addClass('scrolled')
    ) : (
      $('.fixed-nav-bar').removeClass('scrolled'),
      $('.the-bass').removeClass('scrolled')
    );
  });

  // Drop Down Function
  $('#menuButton').on('change', function() {
    ($('#menuButton').is(':checked')) 
      ? ($('.the-bass').addClass('dropped')) 
      : ($('.the-bass').removeClass('dropped'));
  });
  var feedbackSlider = $('.feedback-slider');
  feedbackSlider.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    nav: true,
    dots: true,
    autoplay: true,
    loop: true,
    mouseDrag: true,
    touchDrag: true,
    navText: ["<i class='fa fa-long-arrow-left'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-long-arrow-right'></i>"],
    responsive: {
      // breakpoint from 767 up
      767: {
        nav: true,
        dots: false
      }
    }
  });

  feedbackSlider.on("translate.owl.carousel", function() {
    $(".feedback-slider-item h3").removeClass("animated fadeIn").css("opacity", "0");
    $(".feedback-slider-item img, .feedback-slider-thumb img, .customer-rating").removeClass("animated zoomIn").css("opacity", "0");
  });

  feedbackSlider.on("translated.owl.carousel", function() {
    $(".feedback-slider-item h3").addClass("animated fadeIn").css("opacity", "1");
    $(".feedback-slider-item img, .feedback-slider-thumb img, .customer-rating").addClass("animated zoomIn").css("opacity", "1");
  });
  
  feedbackSlider.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(property) {
    var current = property.item.index;
    var prevThumb = $(property.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).prev().find("img").attr('src');
    var nextThumb = $(property.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).next().find("img").attr('src');
    var prevRating = $(property.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).prev().find('span').attr('data-rating');
    var nextRating = $(property.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).next().find('span').attr('data-rating');
    $('.thumb-prev').find('img').attr('src', prevThumb);
    $('.thumb-next').find('img').attr('src', nextThumb);
    $('.thumb-prev').find('span').next().html(prevRating + '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>');
    $('.thumb-next').find('span').next().html(nextRating + '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>');
  });
  
  $('.thumb-next').on('click', function() {
    feedbackSlider.trigger('next.owl.carousel', [300]);
    return false;
  });
  
  $('.thumb-prev').on('click', function() {
    feedbackSlider.trigger('prev.owl.carousel', [300]);
    return false;
  });
});
```

The website is https://www.dinaledifs.co.za

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"In the body of your question, **start by expanding on the summary you put in the title**. Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself. The first paragraph in your question is the second thing most readers will see, so make it as engaging and informative as possible."_

Comment: What @Andreas said. I clicked just because the title had me laughing out loud. I've never seen a ternary used like this. You sure this works even sometimes?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the console with your site open there's an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

When you refresh the page, this error disappears. The reason is because the `jquery.js` reference has been cached.

The reason for this behaviour is because you've used `async` on the `<script />` reference, yet there's other scripts which rely on jQuery being present. To fix your problem just remove the `async` attribute:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/javascript.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/137e079bdc.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```